# OutOfMemoryException when going back and forth between activities, despite recycling all Bitmaps and collecting garbage

Tags: java, android, memory, bitmap, garbage-collection

This seems like a simple issue, but I can't figure out what's causing it.

I have one activity that creates several Bitmaps using Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Config), applies a Canvas to them, and draws on the canvases. Once I'm done, I recycle them. They are created in the resolution that they are displayed at, and don't have any issues being created. In OnSurfaceDestroyed(), I recycle every Bitmap. As part of the drawing instructions, I do allocate temporary Bitmaps which are recycled as soon as they are unneeded. As an extra measure, I also put System.gc() in every activity's OnSurfaceDestroyed().

Now, when I switch between this activity and another activity (which creates no Bitmaps), I get an OutOfMemoryException after about 6 or 7 switches back and forth. The LogCat makes it clear that each time I create the first activity, more and more space is being freed by the automatic garbage collector. Here is the source error:

```
06-23 12:49:53.984: E/dalvikvm-heap(8487): Out of memory on a 1382416-byte allocation.
```

I realize this is a huge byte allocation, but I don't really understand why? It has no problem the first 5-6 times, so why does the memory seem to accumulate even though I'm recycling everything? I'm fairly certain that nothing else I'm doing is high-memory.

I did find a work-around by using Config.RGB_565 to create the Bitmaps instead of Config.ARGB_8888, but this simply increases the back-and-forth-til-crash count from 6-7 to around 30. It's still accumulating memory for some unknown reason.

Is there something other than recycle() that I can use, or some other system resource that would help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It has no problem the first 5-6 times, so why does the memory seem to accumulate even though I'm recycling everything?

It doesn't accumulate. It fragments. On Java, `OutOfMemoryError` is fairly literal: there is not enough heap space to allocate your desired block. On Android's Dalvik VM, `OutOfMemoryError` is really `ThereIsNoBlockBigEnoughError`, because Dalvik does not have a compacting garbage collector. I go more into what that means (and where the new ART runtime should have an impact) in [a blog post](http://commonsware.com/blog/2014/06/16/art-garbage-collection.html).

> Is there something other than recycle() that I can use, or some other system resource that would help?

Step #1: Set your `android:minSdkVersion` to 11 or higher.

Step #2: Stop recycling your bitmaps. *Reuse* them, using `inBitmap` on `BitmapFactory.Options`. Maintain your own pool of available `Bitmap` objects eligible for recycling for each image resolution you are needing. See [this bit of documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/manage-memory.html#inBitmap) for more.

Comment: I mostly understand what's going on in that documentation, but there's just one confusing part: I'm creating the Bitmaps programatically, not gathering them from files. The documentation specifies that you go through BitmapFactory since you need Options to get inBitmap. Do I need to save my Bitmaps to a file once they are created for the first time, and then retrieve them this way? Seems like an unnecessary step from where I was. I never had to use BitmapFactory in my original process.

Comment: @JohnO.: "I'm creating the Bitmaps programatically, not gathering them from files" -- since I do not know precisely what that means, you may wish to edit your question to explain how you are creating and using them. Off the cuff, you should still be able to reuse them, though, by wiping their current contents and drawing fresh contents, rather than discarding and re-instantiating them every time.

Comment: I create several Bitmaps using Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Config), apply a Canvas to them, and draw on the canvases. Once I'm done, I recycle them. I'll keep looking through the documentation and references until I find a way to make this work.

Comment: @JohnO.: "Once I'm done, I recycle them" -- reuse them for another case where you need a `Bitmap` of the same size. Use `eraseColor()` to wipe out the current contents (and lay down your desired background), then use a `Canvas` to render to it again. Only `recycle()` when you are fairly certain that you will not need another instance of a `Bitmap` at that resolution for a substantial period of time (and for larger resolutions, perhaps a "substantial period of time" == "never").

Comment: So, I've gotten rid of recycle() and consolidated a lot of the code so the memory load is much lower. However, I'm still getting the issue. My problem is that I'm not sure how to "reuse" the Bitmaps that I created in the first Activity. I declare them in the root of the Activity and instantiate them in onCreate(), but onCreate() gets called every time the Activity starts up, which is every time you go from one Activity back to the first. If I can somehow keep the first Activity alive while the other Activities are going, I think this will be sorted out.

Comment: @JohnO.: Most likely they should be maintained in a static cache.

Comment: Okay, I figured it out. It's all sorted out. At some point I commented out finish() during the intents to leave the activity, so OnDestroy() was never called. The Bitmaps were never being erased with eraseColor().